# Facebook Share in emails

Tags: email, facebook

Is it possible to use the Facebook share api within an email?

What i'm trying to achieve is for an email to be sent to someone with a link to a video (or video attached depending on the size).

Within the email would be a Facebook share button that would allow them to upload the video to FB (from a web url).

Thanks

PVS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you'll get is to link the user to Facebook's Sharer.

For example, if you wanted your users to share a link to www.google.com, you'd do this

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com">Share Google!</a>
```

Obviously what you'll really do is use a URL to your domain that holds the content being shared.  For information about specifying the proper meta data (including how to specify a video) see [the documentation for Facebook Share](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share).

Comment: Thanks Peter. That's the route i'm going!